# screen saver and lock not in the same time

Tags: screensaver, screen-lock

i want my mac-book (Mojave 10.14.1) to enter screen saver after a certain time but enter lock after longer time. 
is it possible?

i tried looking for it in screensaver setting and in energy setting without luck. i could only set the screen saver time.

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you want is in preferences -> security and privacy -> general -> require password (some time) after screen sleep or screen saver.

Note that the lock is will happen (some time) after either the screen saver starts or the screen sleeping.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it answers the question